# Determine folder IDs with Invoke-RestMethod on Office 365

Tags: powershell, office365, office365api

When I provide this in PowerShell:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users/andrew.stevens@mydomain.com/folders/"  
  -Credential $cred | foreach-object{$_.value |select DisplayName,ID}
```

I successfully determine Folder IDs, but not all folders are visible. How do I get a complete listing of folders (the one I particular want is recoverable items). I'm thinking once I get the ID I can see the messages the folder would contain?

Comment: Actually getting closer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you  mean the **Deleted Items** folder? 
If I understand correctly, it should be listed by the REST you calling. And we can use the well-known folder names: **DeletedItems** to get the messages. Here is an example for your reference:

```
Get: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/DeletedItems/messages
```

### Update

To use the Office 365 REST API, we need to use the bearer token which we need to register the app first. Below is an sample to get the **access token** via PowerShell for your reference(refer to [Obtaining an Access Token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx#powershellexample)):

```
#region Construct Azure Datamarket access_token 
#Get ClientId and Client_Secret from https://datamarket.azure.com/developer/applications/
#Refer obtaining AccessToken (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx) 

$ClientID = '<Your Value Here From Registered Application>'
$client_Secret = ‘<Your Registered Application client_secret>'

# If ClientId or Client_Secret has special characters, UrlEncode before sending request
$clientIDEncoded = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($ClientID)
$client_SecretEncoded = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($client_Secret)

#Define uri for Azure Data Market
$Uri = "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13"

#Define the body of the request
$Body = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$clientIDEncoded&client_secret=$client_SecretEncoded&scope=http://api.microsofttranslator.com"

#Define the content type for the request
$ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

#Invoke REST method.  This handles the deserialization of the JSON result.  Less effort than invoke-webrequest
$admAuth=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Body $Body -ContentType $ContentType -Method Post

#Construct the header value with the access_token just recieved
$HeaderValue = "Bearer " + $admauth.access_token
#endregion

#region Construct and invoke REST request to Microsoft Translator Service
[string] $text = "Use pixels to express measurements for padding and margins.";
[string] $textEncoded = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($text)
[string] $from = "en";
[string] $to = "de";
[string] $uri = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=" + $text + "&from=" + $from + "&to=" + $to;

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization = $HeaderValue} 
#endregion

$result.string.'#text'
```

After we get the access token, we can use the sample below to make the REST call:

```
$uri ="https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/DeletedItems/messages"

$accessToken=''

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri  -Headers @{Authorization=("bearer {0}" -f $accessToken)}
```

Links below are also helpful for you learning Office 365 REST API:

[Manually register your app with Azure AD so it can access Office 365 APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/add-common-consent-manually)

[Office 365 APIs platform overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/platform-development-overview)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and yes DeletedItems would be the folder name (for deleted items) but I discovered this.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn424760(v=exchg.150).aspx. And from this you can do this..Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users/andrew.stevens@anydomain.com/folders/recoverableitemsdeletions/messages?
" -Credential $cred | foreach-object{$_.value |select @{n='Sender';e={$_.sender.emailaddress.name}},Subject,DateTimeReceived}

Comment: Yes. To use Office 365 REST API, we need to use the bear token. More detail see the update.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment, and yes DeletedItems would be the folder name (for deleted items) but I discovered this..

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn424760(v=exchg.150).aspx.

And from this you can do this..

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users/andrew.stevens@anydomain.com/folders/recoverableitemsdeletions/messages?
" -Credential $cred | foreach-object{$*.value |select @{n='Sender';e={$*.sender.emailaddress.name}},Subject,DateTimeReceived}

So this gets messages in the recovered deleted items container.

Question now is how do I move them to inbox?

//A

Comment: I am following the new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214292/can-i-move-or-copy-messages-office-365-using-the-rest-api-v1-0-using-powershel/38217191#38217191), please check whether it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

OK.. thanks for the information regarding app registration and OAuth. But just to see the recovered deleted items the method using v1.0 does actually work..
What I now need to understand (apologies for my lack of knowledge on this) is how to move messages from the folder located (recovered deleted items) to say the Inbox (or perhaps another folder of choice). Since I was able to use V1.0 (with no requirement for app registration) can I use the same version to do this?
Your answer you provided for sending email worked perfectly and that didnt require any app registration.. so this would be a POST of somekind..

All I have to go on is
1. POST https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/{message_id}/move
2. {
  "DestinationId": "AAMkAGI2NGVhZTVlLTI1OGMtNDI4My1iZmE5LTA5OGJiZGEzMTc0YQAuAAAAAADUuTJK1K9aTpCdqXop_4NaAQCd9nJ-tVysQos2hTfspaWRAAAAAAEJAAA="
}

Which is a folder ID

//A