# Can I move or copy messages (Office 365) using the REST API v1.0 using Powershell

Tags: json, rest, powershell, office365, office365-restapi

So far, thanks kindly to Fei Xue, I have been able to send emails using the REST API. What I would like to know is can I move emails between folders. The following reference (using V1.0) suggests I can..https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#Moveorcopymessages

I have put something together but its not working. The IDs represent the message ID and the destination folder ID

```
$contentType = "application/json"
$uri = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkADRjZmU1Njg3LWU1MTgtNDRlYS1hM2JjLThjYzVlYTNiYjI2NQBGAAAAAACnOSYQcbEERIZTVx5HtMm9BwDzVgO1bziCQLdugqQvOwrTAEVv8cxtAACxp0cQeSQxTYONMj3glZFxAAIF_5u4AAA=?/move"

$body = @{
DestinationID = "AAMkADRjZmU1Njg3LWU1MTgtNDRlYS1hM2JjLThjYzVlYTNiYjI2NQAuAAAAAACnOSYQcbEERIZTVx5HtMm9AQCxp0cQeSQxTYONMj3glZFxAAGmgyRMAAA="
}
$json = $body | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Credential $cred -Body $json -ContentType $contentType
```

Since I can send emails, I would have thought I can move them..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the error message you got? Based on the request, it seems that the $uri is not correct. The message id shouldn't contain the **?**.

Here is an request works welll for your reference:

```
$body="{""DestinationId"":""AQMkADQyZjE2NzY3LWEyNjEtNGI3NwAtOWJhOS1jN2I5NTdkYmY4NmEALgAAA6N9fgB38JpAkbQ1i6fbzV8BAL3QnQZrC1lNpUx8h1pAnzAAAAIBCgAAAA==""}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method post -uri "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkADQyZjE2NzY3LWEyNjEtNGI3Ny05YmE5LWM3Yjk1N2RiZjg2YQBGAAAAAACjfX4Ad-CaQJG0NYun281fBwC90J0GawtZTaVMfIdaQJ8wAAAAAAEMAAC90J0GawtZTaVMfIdaQJ8wAAFYk-FGAAA=/move" -Credential $cred -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
```

Comment: Well I get a "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." without a ? and a "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed." with a ?

Comment: The Move REST API should like **https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{message_id}/move**. Can you get the message via the message id to make sure the message id is correct? And to track more detail error message, you can use the **Fiddler**.

Comment: OK I will use Fiddler.. I did confirm the message ID references the correct message.. So does that mean v1.0 does not provide the opportunity for moving?

Comment: The v1.0 do support the moving message. I have confirmed in the orignal post

Comment: I know this is a step back but I'm having issues capturing traffic from powershell. I've looked all over the net and I'm not making any progress. Surely it cant be that difficult!

Comment: Thanks again.. must have got the IDs wrong.. not sure how, but it works!!!